# The code activates when is not supposed to

Tags: excel, vba

I have been using this code for my checkboxes. What it does is, when you click the checkbox, but Lamar range is `false` it will return the checkbox to false and show the MsgBox, and when Lamar range is `true`, it will let you click the checkbox.

The problem with the code is, sometimes when Lamar range is `true` and you click the checkbox the range will turn `false`and then the code will activate and will return the checkbox to  `false` and give the MsgBox, which I dont want. If the range is `true` and I click the checkbox, it should stay this way even if the range becomes `false` when I do so.

```
Private Sub Checkbox1_Click()
  Static isBusy As Boolean
    Dim LamarC As String

    If Not isBusy Then
        isBusy = True
        
        LamarC = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Checkbox Formulas").Range("E4").Value
        If LamarC = False Then
            Checkbox1.Value = False
            MsgBox "You Are Missing Ingredients", vbCritical, "Missing Ingredients"
        End If
        
        isBusy = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using `Static` for a `Boolean` here - I believe when you do that it keeps the value of `False` and you cannot change it to `True` during run-time. Also, you declare `LamarC` as a `String` but then test it versus a `Boolean` value, why?

Comment: Something is missing. There is no code here that would change the value of a range object, like your "Lamar". You should declare `isBusy` private at module level to make it available to all procedures. Use `CBool` to convert a string to a bool.